# Duplicate Record in one to one relationship when savechange

Tags: entity-framework

i have a one to one relationship between two entity and whn i want set  navigation property add duplication record tu my table

because my English is poor, i attach my Project for you [Here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/5ucn4c5aohk9/n/Sample_rar)

tnx

my code here:

here my Entity:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public int UserType { get; set; }
}

  public partial class Storage : User
{

    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
}

public partial class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }
}
```

here my Add Store botton:

```
    User u = (User)(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        Storage st = new Storage(u);
        Store s = new Store(textBoxStorename.Text);
        s.SetStorage(st);

        s.Save(st);
```

and here my Store Class:

```
    public partial class Store
{

    public Store()
    {

    }


    public Store(string name)
    {

        this.Name = name;



    }

    public void SetStorage(Storage s)
    {
        if (s != null)
        {


            this.Storage = s;
        }

    }





    public void Save(Storage s)
    {


        using (var storekeeper = new TestContainer())
        {
            bool flag = false;
            foreach (var item in storekeeper.Stores)
            {
                if (item.Equals(this))
                {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicat Error", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }



            try
            {



                storekeeper.Users.Attach(s);
                storekeeper.Stores.Add(this);

                storekeeper.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception e )
            {


                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }




        }



    }







    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would encourage you to *try* at least to describe the problem with some code snippets. If you show the relevant code snippets (the entity classes, the code that causes the duplication, etc.) you almost need no English.

Comment: Did you override `Store.Equals` or `Store.GetHashCode`? I don't understand how you could get ever the "Duplicat error" message. `item` in the `foreach` loop is loaded in a new context. `this` comes from outside the context. They must be different objects and `Store.Equals` checks by object reference if not overridden.

Comment: yes,i do.i override Equal method,but my question is about duplication Storage when set store.storage in database

Comment: Anyway, can you show your `Store.Equals`? Is `Equals` in `User` or `Storage` overwritten as well? If yes, please show the method too (you can click the "Edit" link under your question and add more code).

Comment: no,i override Equal method for Store,no for User,why i need to override Equal method,you can download my procect and see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is your data model.

In any case, what's happening is you're recreating the User entity that already exists when you instantiate the new Storage instance.  Storage inherits from User, so storage *is* an instance of user conceptually.  The storage model, however, is different - Storage is a relationship table between User and Store.

By instantiating a new instance of Storage, copying the existing User object's properties to the base properties of the Storage instance, then simply attaching the Storage object to the Users DbSet, entity framework rightly thinks that the object is new and needs to be inserted - including the User entity object.  The user record already exists, hence your duplicate key problem.

Solution: change your data model.  No reason to have the 1..1 relationship entity "Storage".  Simply create a nullable Store property in the User entity.  If you want to enforce that an instance of Store can only be referenced by a single User, then the Store entity should either use the User.Id property as its primary key (with the FK relationship) or have a FK UserId property in Store that must be unique.

Comment: tnx for your answer,but i have several class inherted from user such as:Accountant and Admin.if i create a relation between User and Store,for example a Admin can insert in Store.Storage and this Problem is match with OO Programing?? can you give a better solution ?

Comment: Not really following what you're saying here... you don't want certain entities derived from User to have a Store property?  If that's the case, Admin should derive directly from User; Storage should derive from User, and any entities currently derived from User that you wish to have access to the Store property should derive from Storage.  Interesting application of TPT... is this what you're after?